# Archiving email messages to google docs account.

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to archive all email messages of one google apps account to  another google apps account.
user1@example.com of email messages archive to user2@example.com docs account

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Google Apps Script, you could use a utility like TrueSwitch to move messages from one account to another.